# Why Stable Diffusion model in .mlpackage not need 'vocab.json' and 'merges.txt' but .mlmodelc need?

Tags: python, swift

[ml-stable-diffusion](https://github.com/apple/ml-stable-diffusion) image generation using python with .mlpackage format stable diffusion models. And there is neither 'vocab.json' nor 'merges.txt' file in the folder.

But if generating images using swift cli, .mlmodelc format stable diffusion models need both 'vocab.json' and 'merges.txt' files.

I am so confused that why these 2 files won't be needed when the stable diffusion models are in .mlpackage format? I checked the conversion source code but it seems no need when using .mlpackage format.